# Is there a way to make smart_listing jump to the last page at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smart-listing

I would like to make smart_listing jump to the last page by default, showing the most recent items, if no explicit page is given.

The only way I found to do this is to explicitly calculate the page number myself, like in

.../topics?topics_smart_listing[page]=17

I tried to use "total_pages" etc. on the collection, but apparently this doesn't work. Any suggestions on how I could get the maximum page count, without calculation it myself?